# How to Simplify .htaccess Rewriterule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, simplification

Is it possible to simplfy these RewriteRules? I've hundreds of similar entries in my `.htaccess` file and it seems not to be the best way to set a 410 Header.

```
RewriteRule ^pageID_9363511.html - [G]
RewriteRule ^pageID_9363511_2.html - [G]
RewriteRule ^ci_8819019/thumb_11725326.JPG - [G]
…
…
```

Thank you

Comment: Why are you doing this anyway? What's wrong with just letting the server send a 404 as normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [rewrite map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) like this:

```
pageID_9363511.html -
pageID_9363511_2.html -
ci_8819019/thumb_11725326.JPG -
```

Then you lookup the requested URI path like this:

```
RewriteCond ${gone:$0} =-
RewriteRule .+ - [G]
```

The only simplification is that you don’t need the repetitive `RewriteRule` and `[G]`. And with a rewrite map of the type *dbm* you could even have an access time of O(1) instead of O(*n*).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all those rewritrules and say:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Now just make a 404.html file and it will send all missing files to there. The 410 error message is rarely if ever shown in practice as it refers to a missing server as opposed to a missing file: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E410.html